# Best way to return data to MainActivity from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask, static-methods

I'm using an `ASyncTask` in my app to get some data (a short URL) via a REST API from a web service (Bitly).

When the `ASyncTask` completes I want to pass the result back to my `MainActivity`.

Getting the data back to the `MainActivity` is acheievd by using the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`.

I've read and read and read about how to do this and there seem to be two general approaches.

Originally I was using a 'WeakReference' approach whereby at the start of the `AsyncTask` class you create a weak reference to your `MainActivity` as follows:

```
private class getShortURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakReference;

    myASyncTask(MainActivity activity) {
        mainActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }
{etc etc}
```

With this approach your `AsyncTask` class sits outside of your `MainActivity` class and so a lot of things need to be referenced via the weak reference.

This worked fine (except I suspected - possibly incorrectly - that this weak reference may have been the cause of occassional NPEs), but I then found another way of doing things.

This second approach involved moving the `ASyncTask` class inside of the `MainActivity` class.

This way I was able to access everything that was accessible in the `MainActivity` class directly, inlcuding UI elements and methods defined in the `MainActivity`. It also means that I can access resources such as strings etc and can generate `toasts` to advise the user what is happening.

In this case the whole of the `WeakReference` code above can be removed and the `AsyncTask` class can be made private.

I am also then able to do things like this directly in `onPostExecute` or to keep this in a method within the `MainActivity` that I can call directly from `onPostExecute`:
        shorten_progress_bar.setIndeterminate(false);
        shorten_progress_bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

```
    if (!shortURL.equals("")) {
        // Set the link URL to the new short URL
        short_link_url.setText(shortURL);
    } else {
        CommonFuncs.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.unable_to_shorten_link));
        short_link_url.setHint(R.string.unable_to_shorten_link);

    }
```

(note that `CommonFuncs.showMessage()` is my own wrapper around the toast function to make it easier to call).

BUT, Android Studio then gives a warning that "the `AsyncTask` class should be static or leaks might occur".

If I make the method static I then get a warning that the method from the `MainActivity` that I want to call from `onPostExecute` cannot be called as it is non-static.

If I make that method from `MainActivity` a static method, then it cannot access string resources and any other methods that are non static - and down the rabbit hole I go!

The same is true, as you would expect, if I just move the code from the method in the `MainActivity` into the `onPostExecute` method.
So...

- Is having an AsyncTask as a non-static method really a bad thing? (My
  app seems to work fine with this warning in AS, but I obviously don't
  want to be creating a memory leak in my app.
- Is the `WeakReference` appraoch actually a more correct and safer approach?
- If I use the `WeakReference` approach, how can I create things like `toasts` which need to be run on the UI thread and access string
  resources etc from the `MainActivity`?

I read somewhere about creating an `interface` but got a bit lost and couldn't find that again. Also would this not have the same kind of reliance on the `MainActivity` that a `WeakReference` does and is that a bad thing?

I'm really looking for best practice guidance on how to get some data back to the `MainActivity` and the UI thread from an `AsyncTask` that is safe and doesn't risk memory leaks.

Comment: Strange story. I have so many AsyncTasks in activities and never got a warning like that. Please remove your own toasts from the task to see if that makes nay difference.

Comment: Removing the toasts makes no difference. In fact I had these issues long before I added the toasts.

Answer (score 2):

> Is having an AsyncTask as a non-static method really a bad thing? (My app seems to work fine with this warning in AS, but I obviously don't want to be creating a memory leak in my app.

Yes, your Views and your Context will leak.

Enough rotations and your app will crash.

> Is the WeakReference approach actually a more correct and safer approach?

It's lipstick on a dead pig, WeakReference in this scenario is more-so a hack than a solution, definitely not *the* correct solution.

What you're looking for is a form of event bus from *something* that outlives the Activity.

You can use either retained fragments* or Android Architecture Component ViewModel for that.

And you'll probably need to introduce Observer pattern (but not necessarily LiveData).

> If I use the WeakReference approach, how can I create things like toasts which need to be run on the UI thread and access string resources etc from the MainActivity?

Don't run that sort of thing in `doInBackground()`.

> I'm really looking for best practice guidance on how to get some data back to the MainActivity and the UI thread from an AsyncTask that is safe and doesn't risk memory leaks.

The simplest way to do that would be to use [this library](https://github.com/Zhuinden/event-emitter) (or write something that does the same thing yourself, up to you), put the `EventEmitter` into a `ViewModel`, then subscribe/unsubscribe to this EventEmitter inside your Activity.

```
public class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private final EventEmitter<String> testFullUrlReachableEmitter = new EventEmitter<>();

    public final EventSource<String> getTestFullUrlReachable() {
        return testFullUrlReachableEmitter;
    }

    public void checkReachable() {
        new testFullURLreachable().execute() 
    }

    private class testFullURLreachable extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> { 
        ... 
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            testFullUrlReachableEmitter.emit(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your Activity/Fragment

```
private MyViewModel viewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    // ...
}

private EventSource.NotificationToken subscription;

@Override
protected void onStart() { 
    super.onStart();
    subscription = viewModel.getTestFullUrlReachable().startListening((result) -> {
        // do `onPostExecute` things here
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() { 
    super.onStop();
    if(subscription != null) {
        subscription.stopListening();
        subscription = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.... That's a lot to take in! It's going to take a while for me to have a play with that to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce btw, I wasn't trying to pop up toasts or access string resources in the doInBackground() method, only in the onPostExwcute() method.

Comment: OK..struggling with this. `ViewModelProviders` can't be resolved. The `onStart()` code includes a lambda which I have not used before - another rabbit hole to dive down to understand that. Plus The ViewModel stuff isn't happy when I add that either (`Invalid method declaration; return type required.` on ViewModel).

Comment: I've also updated the original question as the first code sample which shows the WeakReference was actually from the wrong method (which is also causing me some confusion in understanding this solution as I'm having to translate method names - doh!)